# Svg and Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I don't understand how operate svg with highcharts...

I want to do this 3d chart:

http://baering.github.io

I see the source code, and understand that is made with highcharts-3d.js and highcharts.js

For the same chart (but little bit small and less difficult) the code is very easy...
But if see the html code of that page, i see that there is tag svg (and its children tags...)

with svg is possible customize the 3d chart???
How???

The svg is added with code in js ?

Help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts create SVG tags using there library, u cant not change them or its tough to change instead , you can configure chart by JSON it is simple than modification of SVG tags

Comment: Guys thank you very much! I didn't understand... so the tag svg are create only using there library. Thanks !!

Comment: @Rodrigoson6, make it answer of u r question

Answer (score 1):

The highcharts is library which creates SVG elements, but you can configure options by json.

For further information please visit the website:

- http://www.highcharts.com/docs